# JSONArray object not showing on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts, arrays

I am stuck in this. please help me out.

I am using struts1.2. I have made JSONArray of JSONObjects in one of my form defined in struts-config.xml. I want to use this JSONArray on my jsp. I am not able to do this.. please help me out in this .

My stuts-config code is

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="Admin" type="form.adminForms.Admin" />
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/adminLoginAction" type="action.adminActions.AdminLoginCheck" name="Admin">
    <forward name="success" path="baseLayoutAdmin" />
    <forward name="failure" path="loginFailure" />
</action>
</action-mappings>
```

My tiles-defs.xml

```
<definition name="baseLayoutAdmin" path="/adminJSP/newsletter.jsp">
    <put name="title" value="AMSS::NL::Control Panel" />
    <put name="header" value="../adminJSP/header.jsp" />
    <put name="secondHeader" value="../adminJSP/belowHeader.jsp" /> 
    <put name="center" value="../adminJSP/center.jsp" />
    <put name="right" value="../adminJSP/right.jsp" />
    <put name="footer" value="/adminJSP/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

I want to use my form attribute on center.jsp (defined above !!)

center.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"  %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.json.JSONArray" %>
<form name="Admin" method="post">
    ${Admin.userName}
    ${Admin.listOfExcelFileJSONArray}
</form>
```

In above , userName is showing but listOfExcelFileJSONArray is not showing. Both attributes are set in my form.

Please provide me a way to use this JSONArray on JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah.. I have missed a basic thing in my form Admin i.e. I have  not made getters and setters for listOfExcelFileJSONArray variable !!

As I made these , its comming on JSPs too. !!